# как в процесcе создания нового пользователя извлечь сгенерированный id

Tags: java, selenium

Регистрирую в приложении нового пользователя. Ему присваивается id. В ходе тестирования создания пользователя мне надо проверить его наличие в списке пользователей, то есть хочу сверить присвоенный id с id с id в списке пользователя. Как мне в ходе регистрации получить id пользователя. Я регистрирую пользователя через фронт, а получить данные надо по API?

Comment: Ну id хоть как присваивается в базе данных. Вы можете после регистрации попробовать запросить пользователя

Comment: Если сервер не возвращает id , то получить его невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю этот ужасно сформулированный вопрос, то через UI с помощью Selenium в базу заводится новый пользователь, а затем надо проверить корректно ли завелся этот пользователь в базу. С помощью одного только селениума (так как это фреймворк для тестирования фронта) это сделать нельзя, нужно устанавливать соединение с базой данных и чекать запись там, например, с помощью JDBC